# Can't retrieve object from view to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to retrieve object from view to controller. The problem is that the `modeList` in `wrapper` in `saveMode` method is null while debug. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Important: in the browser objects from `modeList` are present in table.

`Mode` is entity table.

Frontend:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th th:text="stat"></th>
        <th th:text="Mode"></th>
        <th th:text="'In use'"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form th:action="@{/editMode}" method="post">
        <tr th:each="mode, stat : ${wrapper.modeList}">
            <td th:text="${stat}"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="actAs" name="actAs" th:value="${mode.actAs}"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="inUse" th:value="true" th:checked="${mode.inUse}"/></td>

        </tr>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSaveMode" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-outline-success"/>
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Backend:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    List<Mode> modeList = modeService.findAll();
    ModeWrapper wrapper = new ModeWrapper();
    wrapper.setModeList(modeList);
    model.addAttribute("wrapper", wrapper);

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/editMode", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "btnSaveMode")
public ModelAndView saveMode(@ModelAttribute("wrapper") ModeWrapper wrapper, BindingResult errors) {

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

ModeWrapper

```
public class ModeWrapper {

    private List<Mode> modeList;

    public List<Mode> getModeList() {
        return modeList;
    }

    public void setModeList(List<Mode> modeList) {
        this.modeList = modeList;
    }
}
```

Debugging is stopped on the `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/")`, before index is rendered.
[image]

Comment: Where in your code do you have this break-point?

Answer (score 0):

Model attributes are not preserved across different request scopes. So you lose value of `modeList` once your `index` view has rendered. You can only get `modeList` in method `saveMode`, if you are sending it in the form data.

Comment: I've updated my post "Debugging is stopped on the return new ModelAndView("redirect:/"), before index is rendered. "